# Why adding less than optimal level water but just enough water to drench the sausage in general isn't the quickest way to cook?

Tags: heat-transfer

The exact reason why adding less than optimal level water but just enough water to drench and dive the whole sasuage in during boiling in a pot isn't the optimal quicking cooking method? My intiuion is that adding a swimming pool of water or a few drip of water won't cook the sasuage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the sausage is completely immersed, you have optimized heat transfer between the water and the sausage, which will yield the shortest cooking time. Furthermore, by putting in no more water than necessary to accomplish this, you have minimized the heat-up time for the pot and water.